# React async await function blocks useDispatch in execution order

Tags: javascript, async-await, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I have a React hook component that the onChange event will execute an aync-await function and a few dispatch, in my mockup test the `store.dispatch` was not detected to be called if I placed my `await function` ahead of any dispatch, it would only detect being called if I placed the dispatch before await function, for example

```
const onChange = async (userId) => {
    await someAsyncFn(userId);
    dispatch(selectUser(userId));    //not detected
    dispatch(selectGroup(userId);    //not detected
};
--Test.js
expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2) ---failed, only receive 0 times
```

but if I placed the await after my dispatch, the test case passed

```
const onChange = async (userId) => {
    dispatch(selectUser(userId));     //detected
    dispatch(selectGroup(userId);     //detected
    await someAsyncFn(userId);
};
--Test.js
expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2) ---passed receive 2 times
```

However, if my placed the await in between of my dispatch, only the dispatch above being detected

```
const onChange = async (userId) => {
    dispatch(selectUser(userId));     //detected
    await someAsyncFn(userId);
    dispatch(selectGroup(userId);     //not detected
};
--Test.js
expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2) ---failed, only detect selectUser being called
```

When I run my application, there is no real difference UI behavior in between the above 3 cases, both dispatch happened as well as my await function, but I am kind of confused, why would my test case not be able to detect my dispatch? Is there anyway to bypass or force to resolve my await method from test case?

Comment: and you are sure that the promise is being resolved or rejected... ? may be the promise is not being rejected or resolved. (may be it is timing out and breaking the code ?)

Comment: In real application it's resolved, but are you referring when executed inside Jest test? Is there any way to by pass the async await?

Comment: I have mocked my async function to be resolved by using `mockResolvedValue`, and I can test to verify the async function being called, however the dispatch seems still not trigger

Comment: Please, post all relevant code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown what's going on. That it works in one case and not work in another suggests that there's race condition somewhere and it is avoided with `await` delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take into account that `await` is used to wait for an asynchronous task. Hence, when you call `await` within in an `async` method, the code that follows will not execute until the asynchronous task has resolved.

Most probably, you are not waiting in your test code for the asynchronous code to resolve. That causes that all that comes after the `await` will not be taken into account in your test.

To wait for the asynchronous code to resolve, you have to define your test as `async` and `await` for your method under test:

```
test('testing on change', async () => {

    // Perform the call to the onChange method. Await for it to resolve.
    await onChange();

    // At this point, the calls to dispatch will have been done independently of their order in the onChange method.
    expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)
});
```

Comment: Thank you! But seems like I cannot call my onChange directly, my onChange was bind to my select dropdown, I am testing all internal method being called within my onChange by performing the simulate  "change" through mount DOM, is there any way to simulate await here? BTW, if I do the await here, does the code execute in behind would really execute whatever in my someAsyncFn while running the test ? My actual someAsyncFn was loading some image file through http call

Comment: Or is there any way I can force my someAsyncFn to be resolved, I don't care if it does the real job while testing, just want to make sure it's been called along with my two dispatch method while performs the change event?

Comment: Also I am not quite sure which would be the best way to order my someAsyncFn with my dispatch from performance perspective, I learned that JavaScript are always synchronized, there's no business logic that which one would go first, is there any performance difference if I do await->dispatch 1->dispatch 2 vs dispatch 1->dispatch 2->await?